# Book about two kids sucked into a video game who fight evil radishes

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to recall a book I frequently read as a child.

The plot revolves around two kids getting sucked into a video game, and the major thing that’s sticking out to me is that they fought evil radishes.

The artwork was 8-bit style.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year you read this, and when you think it might've been published.

Comment: My goodness, [the things Google finds ...](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54438879-radishes)

Comment: @JohnRennie I really want to know why it's called Radishes.  I also really don't want to know why it's called Radishes.